# Create Neural Network is missing from Analyze Tab in Spss 19.0

Tags: spss

I want to create Neural Networks using the IBM SPSS 19.0 version. I read the manual and it says that you go to Analyze -> Neural Networks but I cannot find any Neural Networks at this tab. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

NN is an optional feature that you probably don't have.  Go to the Add-ons menu (not available in all versions) to see what options you have not licensed.